# Is Cracking of Every HydroCarbon Family possible? (Alkane ,Alkenes,Arenes)

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons

I know Cracking is usually used to crack alkanes to get smaller hydrocarbons (as they are easier to ignite) and alkenes(as they have more industrial uses)...but can we crack arenes and alkenes as they are also included in hydrocarbons definition.
But I really doubt about cracking of benzene as lot of energy is required to destroy the delocalised ring. But given infinite energy that is surely possible.... but the product won't be stable... :/

Comment: Hint: All those .... make a text hard to read.

Answer (score 5):

Simple arenes (benzene, toluene, xylenes) are a typical product of a steamcracker. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cracking_(chemistry)#Thermal_methods

Catalytic hydrocracking otoh. (with added hydrogen at high pressure) leads to an increase in the aliphatic fraction and lowers the aromatic content. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cracking_(chemistry)#Hydrocracking

in itself, benzene is quite stable. It's a questions if it has sth. to react with.